# Trying to save .vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component, sfc

I am trying to save a .vue file. I have installed vue cli. When I run the vue serve an error message displays in the command prompt which says "valid entry file should be one of:main.js, index.js, app.vue, App.vue"

Comment: As the error message clearly states, it is not able to locate the entry file. So, can you tell us where exactly the entry file located?

Answer (score 1):

You should run `npm run build` rather than `vue build`.

They are two different commands.

1. `npm run build` runs vue-cli-service build underlyingly, and its
   default entry is src/main.js.
2. `vue build` is for instant prototyping only. Its default entry is one
   of main.js, index.js, App.vue or app.vue in the current directory.

Comment: you should try npm run build.

Comment: it says npm err! missing script: build

Comment: You need to be in the same repertory where your files are, then do `npm run build`

Comment: Where all my html files are? Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Try where your js or json files are. No worry it's a pleasure.

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working I can't save the .vue file

Answer (score 0):

[image: Folder structure]

As you can see in the image above, main.js file is located in the src folder. I specified the path to the main.js file in the package.json file as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vue serve src/main.js",
    "prod": "vue build src/main.js"
}
```

And then I could simply run

> npm run dev

for serving the project in the development environment and

> npm run prod

for creating a production build under dist folder